# How Make a button dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, simplebutton

I'm doing a "list" of buttons, like a Menu in a Form, and I'm trying to do it out of a table in a database, I'm doing this like this:

```
foreach (Catalogos catalogo in catalogos)
{
    SimpleButton sb = new SimpleButton();
    sb.Text = catalogo.Nombre;
    sb.Click += catalogo.Evento;
    LayoutControlItem item = new LayoutControlItem();
    item.TextVisible = false;
    item.Control = sb;
    lcg.Add(item);
 }
```

My problem is in the `sb.Click += catalogo.Evento` line, how can I do the eventy dynamically

Comment: What is the problem?  You should be able to set the click event handler as long as `Evento` has the correct signature.

Comment: What type is Evento (Catalogo.Evento)? De qué tipo es la propiedad Evento (Catalogo.Evento)?

Comment: I doning it string, I know it must be a EventHandler or something like that, but how can I store that on a BD?

Btw, I am trying the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda / anonymous method

```
SimpleButton sb = new SimpleButton();
sb.Text = catalogo.Nombre;
sb.Click += (sender, evntArgs) => {
    //some dynamic mouse click handler here.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**option 1**

Create a `SimpleButton_Click` method in your form

```
private void SimpleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //using (SimpleButton)sender you can find which botton is clicked
}
```

then in your loop, assign that method to `Click` event:

```
sb.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SimpleButton_Click);
```

**option 2**

assign a delegate/lambda expression to event this way:

```
//instead of sender and e, usually you should use different names
//because usually you are running this code in an event handler
//that has sender and e parameters itself
sb.Click += (object senderObject, EventArgs eventArgs) => 
{
   //using (SimpleButton)sender you can find which botton is clicked
};
```

Comment: @caesay I think it adds some value :) and here is a +1 for you to don't think bad :)